# How can I hide an API key using android studio Giraffe?

Tags: android, android-studio

Before you would add the API key to local.properties and then in the app build.gradle you would add the following code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream()) 
buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty('API_KEY')}\""
```

however, now it will give me an error in Properties saying that can't find the element.
How is this done now?

Answer (score 0):

I use `gradle.ext.yourPropertyName` in build.gradle to access custom properties set in local.properties and it still works now. Just change `yourPropertyName` to your own property name.